# How to use com.android.internal.CallManager in Android app

Tags: android, telephony

**UPDATES:**

"Please see the comment below for the newest states."

I am trying to use this Class "com.android.internal.CallManager" in my app. I have studied this topic for several days. However, I found nothing but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652660/accessing-callmanager-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745899/how-to-access-com-android-internal-telephony-callmanager). They both can't solve my problem. I used two ways to invoke Android's hidden API.

1) The first way I use to invoke the hidden API is Java Reflection. Here is my sample code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = context.getClass().getClassLoader();
final Class<?> callManagerClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager");

Method getInstanceMethod = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance");
getInstanceMethod.setAccessible(true);
mCallManager = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null);

mActiveFgMethod = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("hasActiveFgCall");
Object res = mActiveFgMethod.invoke(mCallManager);

boolean result = ((Boolean) res).booleanValue();
```

As you see, I use Java Reflection to access CallManager and access the function "hasActiveFgCall" then. But whatever the phone state is, the result would be **false**.

2) The second way I use is like what this site([http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/)/) used. The following is the sample code.

```
import com.android.internal.telephoney.CallManager;

CallManager mCallManager = CallManager.getInstance();
boolean result = mCallManager.hasActiveFgCall();
```

I downloaded and compiled Android 4.1.2 source code. The jar file was this  "out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar". I could successfully invoked the class and the function. Unfortunately, the result is the same, **false**.

The following is the permissions I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
```

I have checked the code of this class file (CallManager.java) and found the function call list: hasActiveFgCall() --> getFirstActiveCall() --> isIdle(). I thought I misunderstood the phone state, so I wrote an app to verify the phone state. The code is as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Telephony";

    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) 
                this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        mTelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), 
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        t1.setText("listen the state of phone:\n"); 
    }

    class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.e(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDEL");
                t1.append("CALL_STATE_IDLE"+"\n");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.e(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                t1.append("CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK" + "\n");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.e(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
                t1.append("CALL_STATE_RINGING"+"\n");
                break;

            default:
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I was right. No matter what the phone state was, such as OFFHOOK, IDLE and RINGING, the function "hasActivieFgCall()" returned false. This is very frustrating.

Any reply would be appreciated.

Comment: what permissions does you're app have. There could be permissions checks to prevent your app and apps like yours from obtaining information from internal api classes that are hidden from the sdk ... for a reason.

Comment: @QuentinSwain thank you for your comment. I tried to add some permissions into the app. For example, I choosed all the permissions applied by Android's Phone.apk and deleted some permissions not for third-party app. However, nothing has changed. I couldn't get the right result.

Comment: What permissions did you try to add? Are you building your app with eclipse of do you have a full checkout of AOSP? Have you looked at the source for the TelephonyManager/ Telephony Services ?

Comment: @QuentinSwain I have listed the permissions above. They were from the Android's Phone.apk without some permissions not for third-party app. Yes, I build my app with eclipse and I have check some code in AOSP such as Phone.apk and the package "framework/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/" and "framework/base/telephony/java/android/telephony". However, nothing could help.

Comment: What I wanted to use CallManager to get is the Phone's states. However, after reading the code again, I found that I was wrong. Although I invoked CallManager.getInstance(), I just got it in my app environment which means that I could only get the state of the phones in my app. There is no phone registered in my app and I can't register the Phone.apk's phone in my app. So if I invoked Callmanager class, I got nothing. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the Service like ITelephony which can be used by Java Reflection and aidl. I think the only way to use `CallManager` is to give your app the system permission

you need to signapk your apk and add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in your mainfest file.

Comment: Thank you, @Akachy. Actually, I used to see a method that could use ITelephony by aidl and make a phone call without the user's attention. I couldn't find the exact URL that I saw it. But I am sure it could be done.