# Convert Call.Callback class from Android Java to Xamarin Android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I already convert overall of the source code but for Call.Callback is unable to convert is there anywhere to use it on C#, Sorry that I am new on Xamarin (C#).
In Additional, I would like to using "callback" in RegisterCallBack(), it work on java but not in c#.

```
private Call.Callback callback = new Call.Callback() {
    public void onStateChanged(Call call, int state) {
        
    }
}; 
public void onCallAdded(Call call)
    {
        call.RegisterCallback(callback);
        PhoneCallManager.call = call;
    }
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Also, please show one place (in other code), where `callCallback` is used. This will help the understanding of what fix is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is the anonymous inner class in Java. For C#, if you want to add or override a method in a class, you need to create a class to extend it and then add or override the method you want. Such as:

```
public class MyCallback : Call.Callback
{
    public void onStateChanged(Call call, int state)
    {
        CallManager.updateCall(call);
    }
}
```

In addition, how do you get the CallManager? I had checked the resource code of the Call.Callback, there is no instance of CallManager in it. According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745899/how-to-access-com-android-internal-telephony-callmanager), it seems that you need to use the classloader to get the CallManager.

**Update**

```
private MyCallback callback = new MyCallback();

public void onCallAdded(Call call)
{
    call.RegisterCallback(callback);
    PhoneCallManager.call = call;
}
```

Comment: CallManager that used in my code is class name that created by my own. I edited my question, may I know how to implement the callback to use in RegisterCallBack() ?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.Had you tried the code I provided? Just create a callback class to implement the Call.Callback and then register it.@KelvinTan